# How to set a variable for a model in another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So basically I have a model called "Charge" that I want to use to generate invoices.

```
class Charge < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :client
 
 def invoice
  Receipts::Invoice.new(
    id: id,
    issue_date: Date.today,
    due_date: Date.today + 30,
    status: "<b><color rgb='#5eba7d'>PAID</color></b>",
    bill_to: [
      "#{client.full_name}",
      nil,
      "mail@example.com"
    ],
    company: {
      name: "Teste LTDA",
      address: "Avenida Paulista, 648, apto 503 bloco 01",
      email: "teste@teste.com",
    },
    line_items: [
      ["<b>Item</b>", "<b>Unit Cost</b>", "<b>Quantity</b>", "<b>Amount</b>"],
      ["GoRails Subscription", "$19.00", "1", "$19.00"],
      [nil, nil, "Subtotal", "$19.00"],
      [nil, nil, "Tax Rate", "0%"],
      [nil, nil, "Total", "$19.00"],
    ],
  )
 end
end
```

In this way, I can access clients infos, like "client.full_name". But my client model is linked to my "Address" model, like this:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client, optional: true
end
```

In this way, I thought that I could set inside my "Charge" model something like:

```
@address = Address.find_by(client_id: client_id)
```

But when I try to generate my invoice in my show action it shows that it doesn't have a client_id. So I tried write something like this in my model:

```
@address = Address.find(3)
```

But in this case, when I try recover street info in my method, it shows: "undefined method `street' for nil:NilClass"

What can I do? How can I get this information in my model?

Comment: make sure your data is complete when you try your code, are you sure the charge you tried it with had a client?
Also, where are you using `@address` - it looks like an instance varible in the controller, are you using it in the charge model? If yes, pleease edit your code!

Comment: you haven't given enough context for those last bits of code for us to work out what's going on. `@address = Address.find_by(client_id: client_id)` should work inside the `Charge` model if the `Charge` object has a client_id and there's an `Address` object with the same client ID, but there's lots of ways those conditions might not be fulfilled, for example, you haven't shown us where you create any `Address` object. For all we know there are no `Adress` objects in the database.

Comment: My `client` has many addresses, so I think that could be confusing, like I would like to recall just the first object found in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to handle this is by creating a [indirect association](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association) - not by querying by id directly.

```
class Charge < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  has_one :address, through: :client
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address
end
```

And its also very questionable if the generation of invoices belongs in this model to begin with as it should either be a factory method on `Receipts::Invoice` (a class method that creates an instance) or done in something else such as a service object.

Comment: In this case, what migration do I need to generate?

Comment: None. Indirect association join through existing associations and their foreign keys.